# Rigorous but elementary exposition of "div, grad, curl, and all that"

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

What book gives a rigorous but elementary exposition of "div, grad, curl, and all that"?  Conventional second-year calculus books are as far from rigorous as anything ever gets.

Comment: I remember when I was 2nd year student I haven't felt that proofs of Green and Stokes formulas are rigor enough, so +1

Comment: @Gortaur: [As Henri Cartan put it](http://books.google.com/books?id=-CXn6y_1nJ8C&pg=PA4) *[...] the existing textbooks were not satisfactory, especially when it came to multiple integrals and Stokes' theorem. I discussed my concerns several times with André Weil. One beautiful day he told me, 'I've had it, we need to fix this for good. We need to write a good textbook on analysis. Then you'll stop complaining!'* [The rest is history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki).

Comment: @t.b.: I do not complain, I rather recall that the only area in my Analysis course where I felt the lack of rigor was multidimensional integration, especially Fubini's theorem and Green and Stokes formulas. I had a guess what are the reasons - I only wonder how much pages in appendix will take the necessary theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Fleming's [Functions of Several Variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902066)? Relative to most of books that I've looked at, it provides the least amount of machinery necessary to prove (rigorously) the basic theorems of integral vector calculus. I find it to be very readable and easy to understand.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55380/self-contained-treatments-of-stokess-theorem-for-manifolds)  that I posed awhile back which, inexplicably, was closed as being off-topic, might also be relevant.

Comment: The only local library that has that book has two copies and both are currently checked out.  But I'll look at it soon, I think.  Thank you.